# Unreal 5.3 ignores changes in Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, unreal-5, visual-studio-code, build

I’m using Unreal 5.3 on Ubuntu 23.04 “Lunar.” I’m not using Windows (I really can’t stand it), and there is no Visual Studio on Linux. (It's not even supported by Wine.) But we have VS Code, the development platform that Epic and Unreal recommend for Linux. So far so good.

My only problem is that, when I make a change in my C++ code, my game does not notice. (Yes, I did save, otherwise VS Code would not build the changes at all.) If I close the whole game window and then start the editor from VS Code, with the option `Launch GameNameEditor (Development) (workspace)`, the editor will eventually open with the changes. But I can’t, in practice, close and reopen the editor at every single change in the code. I tried running `make GameNameEngine` from the terminal. That too builds the game, but the editor still ignores the changes.

The simplest change I make to verify that there is a change is change the name of a `UPROPERTY` variable editable in the “Details” pane of the editor. Or add or remove some. It usually takes me hours of attempts to see them appear, get removed, or get modified. Again: the problem seems to *only* be that the editor ignores the changes.

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks.